# Big O notation of max?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm coding a few set comparisons and noting their big O's using different algorithms and set implementations. I got to one particular function and I decided that it is $O(max(n,m))$ runtime. Is that the proper way to express this?

Comment: No problem with that.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455942/understanding-time-complexity-of-omaxm-n/19458485#19458485

Answer (score 9):

The expression $O(\max(n,m))$ is meaningful, and we even have $O(n) + O(m) = O(n+m) = O(\max(n,m))$.

Comment: Just to clarify: $O(n) + O(m)$ is the maximum of n and m? I've only really used expressions like $O(1)$, $O(n log n)$. I haven't seen any 'operators' or anything before.

Comment: @LeviMorrison What do you mean by the `maximum of n and m`? If you're wondering about the $=$ there, yes, these do hold.

Comment: Meaning, the runtime is equal to $O(n)$ if n > m, and $O(m)$ otherwise.

Comment: @LeviMorrison Yes, the argument is quite simple: Suppose $n > m$ and your function is in $\mathcal{O}(n + m)$: Then your function is also in  $\mathcal{O}(n + n)$, which is the same as $\mathcal{O}(n)$ Combine that with the argument for $m > n$ and you can see that it also being in $\mathcal{O}(\text{max}(n, m))$ makes sense. Note that adding $\mathcal{O}$s together is a slight abuse of notation.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus. What "expression is meaningful" means?  And BTW, I have my own, open [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366904/comparing-complexity-of-onm-and-omaxn-m) in StackOverflow.   You are welcome to claim 200 bounty points there.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky By "meaningful" I meant "has a meaning and can be (and is) used in mathematical communication, e.g. in a paper".